# Upload image with python

Tags: python-2.7, ftplib

I'm using this command to ftp upload a png image. But when I upload the image is not visible it looks like currupted even if I download it I can't view the image.
Here is the code

ftp.storlines('STOR ' + 'Simple.png', open('Simple.png', 'rb'))

here is the uploaded file
http://llgrow.co.nf/Simple.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `ftp.storlines()` is sending the file in ascii mode, you should use `ftp.storbinary()` for an image file (binary mode):

```
    F=open("Simple.png","rb")
    ftp.storbinary('STOR image.png',F,1024)
```

Comment: I tried your code but the error ooks the same here is the same file uploaded with your code  http://llgrow.co.nf/Simple.png

Comment: Do you have the file permissions set correctly on the image before trying to ftp it?

Comment: yes I'm uploadin the png image and some html files the html files are ok here : http://llgrow.co.nf/RPT0001.HTM

Comment: I Tried this and still the same error: ftp.storbinary('STOR ' + 'Simple.png', open('Simple.png', 'rb'))

Comment: The problem was with the server I changed the server from the biz.nf hosted to a new server and now it is working  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using storbinary()...

Because it takes the binary values of that image... So that no pixel values are messed up...

Since image files contain pixels... Need to store the exact X,Y positions of the pixels.

So storbinary() does that by default.